# Get Data out of Closure in Swift

Tags: rest, swift, closures

I'm trying to make a test REST Call to `var url : String = "http://ip.jsontest.com/"` with Swift. What I want to do is to show the result (basically just print the JSON) in a UITextView.

Now I want to use this snippet for achieving that:

```
     NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue(), completionHandler:{ (response:NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in 
// code
```

However, I have no idea how to get the data out of the Closure into my UITextView. Printing to Console is no issue, but writing the data to a var and returning that to my TextView is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Complete the closure like below...

EDITED:

```
NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue(), completionHandler:{ (response:NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, error: NSError!) in
if(data != nil){
    //Display the json using your textview object
    //self.textView.text = .... data (convert the data as you wanted.)
    let responseData : NSString = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    self.textView.text = reponseData


 }
})
```

Comment: "terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException", as soon as I try to set the textView.text inside that Closure. Weird, because I can easily println(data), but setting self.textView.text = "\(data)" throws an exception.

Comment: Convert the response from NSData to NSString, then try. As I updated my answer above.

Comment: You also should insure that setting UITextView.text is done on the main UI thread by wrapping it in `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

Basically I can get the data out like this:

```
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())
                {
                    self.resultView.text = "\(data)"

            }
```